# UIButton close to keyboard does not receive touch event

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikeyboard

You can test by yourself by cloning this repo https://github.com/sey/ios-keyboard-test.

The problem is the following:
When you enter text in a `UITextField` and you want to quickly tap a button which position is close to the keyboard the button does not receive touch event at first. You need to wait a small amount of time before tapping on the button does anything.

In the linked project the button action is set to clear the text field. If you enter text and touch the button quickly you will see that the text field does not get cleared and you'll have to touch the button again. If you tap on the button that is on top of the text field (not close to the keyboard) everything work as expected.

I suspect this is a bug from Apple. And I suspect this comes from the fact that some keys on the keyboard show other keys when you long press them (such as E, U). And maybe a hidden frame prevents from touching the button immediately after entering text.

My questions are:

- Can you reproduce the bug?   And do you know if this has already been
- reported with a workaround or else?

[EDIT] Please test in landscape mode.

Comment: where did you test the app??

Comment: Why don't you just submit this as a Bug to apple? If you made a new project and can replicate it yourself that is enough.  Submit it to Apple and they will do the duplicate check and confirm any resolutions that they might find for it. However, it can take a few weeks for them to come back to you. If the issue does not happen if the button is further above the keyboard then adjust the origin based on the keyboard height. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: I tested the app on iPad 3, iOS 6. I didn't submit this already because I wanted to know if someone had a solution. As you say they won't fix this right now and they won't fix this on iOS 6 either (though I didn't mention that in my question).

Comment: i have downloaded and test it but i have not found such issue, its perfectly clearing text on first tap of button.

Comment: Did you test on iOS 6 or 7?

Comment: Clear button is working for me, but strangely I can't use my MacBook keyboard for text input *only* after I change the interface orientation (on iOS7 iPad retina simulator).

Comment: Ahh wait, if I use the simulator keyboard and hit 'y', there is about .2 seconds of non-response from the button, only in landscape. Your hidden frame hypothesis sounds plausible.